# What's the easiest/cleanest way to get the MessageID of a sent email?

Tags: python, django, email-headers

I want to save the MessageID of a sent email, so I can later use it in a References: header to facilitate threading.

I see in root/django/trunk/django/core/mail.py (line ~55) where the MessageID is created.

I'm trying to think of the best way to collect this value, other than just copy/pasting into a new backend module and returning it. Maybe that is the best way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Since you've solved your problem, and documented the answer, please accept that answer as the answer to your question.  That way the other denizens know that you don't need any more assistance with this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I see I was browsing tragically old code. I should be able to call django.core.mail.message.make_msgid() and populate the header myself before calling send.

Answer (score 1):

Not all backends actually support asserting a message id (for e.g. SES sets it's own message ID and returns it in it's send response). You can actually pull out the returned/generated/set message id if you use the newer (circa 1.1?) [EmailMessage](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class) class you can extract the returned message ID from the instance once you call .send(), e.g.:

```
e=EmailMessage(
            subject,
            content,
            from_email,
            recipient_list,
            headers = headers,
        )
 e.send()
 message_id = e.extra_headers.get('Message-Id',None)
```

Comment: How does it work when recipient_list has many email ids. We should get different message_id for different recipient.

Comment: Multiple recipients will all have the same message id, since you don't (even at an SMTP level) create multiple messages, you create one message, and the SMTP protocol handles replicating that message to multiple recipients. I've tested with SES and confirmed.

Comment: I could not get EmailMessage to work, there was no message_id in the variable. I moved to boto, which returns message_id properly and (message_id, email) is my unique key. But I lose the efficiency of using SMTP over using API.

Comment: Does not work on my Django setup, returned id is `None`.

Comment: Nothing in the current code of mail backends included in django handles the message-id. Except for 3rd-party backends, this is not supposed to work